# Is there a “createObject” in java?

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, vba

In VBScript (and VBA/VB6) there is a function called `CreateObject`

like this:

> ```
> Dim ExcelApp As Object
> Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> ```

The above code creates an instance of the `Excel.Application` class, **without requiring an early-bound reference** to the `Excel` type library.

Is there something comparable in Java?

Comment: Yes, it is called `new`

Comment: AFAIK, In java we use `new` keyword to create an object of a class.
EX : `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: There's also a [newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method:

Comment: Only an `Excel.Workbook` object can create an `Excel.Sheet` AFAIK. Did you mean to illustrate with `Excel.Application`?

Answer (score 3):

There are four different ways (I really don’t know is there a fifth way to do this) to create objects in java:

1. Using new keyword
   This is the most common way to create an object in java. I read somewhere that almost 99% of objects are created in this way.

   ```
   MyObject object = new MyObject();
   ```
2. Using Class.forName()
   If we know the name of the class & if it has a public default constructor we can create an object in this way.

   ```
   MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();
   ```
3. Using clone()
   The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing object.

   ```
   MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject(); 
   MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();
   ```
4. Using object deserialization
   Object deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its serialized form.

   ```
   ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream ); 
   MyObject object = (MyObject) inStream.readObject();
   ```

Now you know how to create an object. But its advised to create objects only when it is necessary to do so.

From https://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/different-ways-to-create-objects/